# Ajax call fails when using wp_remote_get in wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am having issues with `wp_remote_get` in my Wordpress plugin.

What I want to do is call a method inside my main public class with ajax. But the thing is that the call fails when the `wp_remote_get` function is used in it. It is supposed to do an API call and return the data to the jQuery. When I comment out the `wp_remote_get` the call works fine and response is given back. Any ideas how can I make this work?

Method that processes the call:

```
    public function countryLookupApiCall() {
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['country'])) {
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $apiKey = $this->getApiKey();
        $url = $this->url . $country . '/callCharges?apiKey=' . $apiKey . '&response=JSON';
        $response = wp_remote_get($url);
        echo $response;
        die();
        }
    }
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#countryLookupForm").submit(function(e){
    var country = jQuery("#selectCountry").val();
    var action = 'countryLookupResponse';

    jQuery.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: countryLookup.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: action, country: country},

        success: function(data) {
            //do something with this data later on
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Wordpress actions are all registered well because the call works when I don't use the wp_remote_get

EDIT:
The solution was more than simple, I just needed to add `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add errors checking into your code. This can help you to figure out what is causing the problem.

```
    public function countryLookupApiCall() {
if (isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['country'])) {
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $apiKey = $this->getApiKey();
    $url = $this->url . $country . '/callCharges?apiKey=' . $apiKey . '&response=JSON';
    $response = wp_remote_get($url);
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        $error_code = $response->get_error_code();
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        $error_data = $response->get_error_data($error_code);
        // Process the error here....
    }
    echo $response;
    die();
    }
}
```

Also you are using **echo** on **wp_remote_get** result. As defined in documentation wp_remote_get returs WP_Error or array instance. So you should use something like this:

```
echo $response['body'];
```

Comment: The problem is that ajax call fails completely if the wp_remote_get is included, as soon as I remove it the call works just fine. I am thinking it could be a some kind of conflict.

Comment: Well... than you need to enable error reporting in your php configuration and set error reporting level to debug. This will get you exact error to move further.

    `error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);`